# How do I make html files accessible from OpenShift server running python?

Tags: python, html, uwsgi, openshift-online-2

I have an OpenShift DIY app running Python. However, I cannot reach static files like html. (or run php) If I try accessing: mydomain.rhcloud.com/hello.html, I get:
**`uWSGI Error`** `Python application not found`.

Could you please help how i can make html files accessible? 
My directories like:

```
repo
   diy
      something.py << It server all requests to the domain, however if it doesn't
      hello.html / exists, than I get the above error
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python cartridges that you get with OpenShift is simply an Apache web serve that uses [mod_wsgi](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to server your content. This means that you content that Apache directs you to most be severed by a mod_wsgi server/components.

Typically with a Python Cartridge you will extend the cartridge with a Web Framework to better help you sever static content such as this. Some examples of typical frameworks that are use are:

- [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)
- [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), see an [example](https://github.com/openshift/flask-example)
- [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/)

However out of the box (unless you are willing to edit your gears **python/etc/conf.d/openshift.conf** file which can break your gear) you can not route to static traffic with out using a [WSGI framework](http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).